# Symfony cannot load resource

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Symfony is giving me this error, at any time I am trying to clear cache or access endpoint.

`Cannot load resource "{"name":"Applicant","path":"%kernel.project_dir%\/src\/Applicant\/UI\/Action\/V1\/","namespace":"App\\Applicant\\UI\\Action\   \V1","type":"attribute"}".`

routes.yaml

```
controllers:
  resource:
    name: Applicant
    path: ../src/Applicant/UI/Action/V1/
    namespace: App\Applicant\UI\Action\V1
    type: attribute

api_login_check:
  path: /api/login_check
```

RegistrationAction

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Applicant\UI\Action\V1;

use App\Applicant\Infrastructure\Mapper\ApplicantRegistrationInputMapper;
use App\Applicant\UI\Input\ApplicantRegistrationInput;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Model;
use OpenApi\Attributes\JsonContent;
use OpenApi\Attributes\RequestBody;
use OpenApi\Attributes\Response as OAResponse;
use OpenApi\Attributes\Tag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

final class RegistrationAction extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    private ApplicantRegistrationInputMapper $registrationInputMapper;

    public function __construct(ApplicantRegistrationInputMapper $registrationInputMapper)
    {
        $this->registrationInputMapper = $registrationInputMapper;
    }

    #[Tag(name: 'Registration')]
    #[OAResponse(response: 201, description: 'Registered')]
    #[OAResponse(response: 400, description: 'Bad request')]
    #[Rest\Post('/api/v1/registration', name: 'api.v1.registration')]
    #[RequestBody(
        required: false,
        content:
        new JsonContent(
            ref: new Model(
                type: ApplicantRegistrationInput::class
            )
        )
    )]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->handleView($this->view(null, 201));
    }
}
```

And my directory structure

[image]

I'm just overlooking something here probably, but I cannot find it for more than two hours now.

I have checked path to the class and namespace.
I also tried to clear cache.
I expected that everything will work as usually but I am still getting this error.